# linux startup script not executing script in user's home directory

Tags: linux, boot, raspberry-pi, init

I want a script on my raspberry pi to run when the system boots.
That's why I've created a script inside /etc/init.d that is linked in /etc/rc2.d

This is the script inside init.d:

```
#! /bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          Scriptname
# Required-Start:
# Required-Stop:
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Kurze Beschreibung
# Description:       Bechreibung
### END INIT INFO



#Switch case fuer den ersten Parameter
case "$1" in
    start)
        #Aktion wenn start aufgerufen wird
        /home/thomas/applications/autostart/autostart.sh
        ;;

    stop)
        #Aktion wenn stop aufgerufen wird
        echo "nope"
        ;;

    restart)
        #Aktion wenn restart aufgerufen wird
        echo "nope"
        ;;
        *)
        #Default Aktion wenn start|stop|restart nicht passen
        echo "(start|stop|restart)"
        ;;
esac

exit 0
```

And this is the content of `/home/thomas/applications/autostart/autostart.sh`:

```
#! /bin/sh
touch /home/thomas/kater
```

when i change the start command inside the script in /etc/init.d to the following lines, the  touch command gets executed:

```
    start)
        #Aktion wenn start aufgerufen wird
        touch /home/thomas/kater
        ;;
```

So why doesn't it execute the seperate script?

Thanks in advance, McFarlane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming what you have shown is exactly what you have, the script won't work because you have a formatting error. There should be no space between `!#` and `/bin/sh` in the shebang line:

```
#!/bin/sh
touch /home/thomas/kater
```

Comment: you are right. but even without the space the touch command is not beeing executed.

Comment: @McFarlane is the script executable? Please [edit] your question and add the output of `ls -l /home/thomas/applications/autostart/autostart.sh`

Comment: the problem was indeed the wrong #!/bin/sh line. I had it wrong in two files that's why it didn't work the first time.